# Kotlin Android Firebase Arraylist plus?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist

[image]

As picture above

When there is data in Firebase

After storing the data in ArrayList
By adding the time saved in Work and Study
I want to get the total amount of how much time I spent on work and study. Please help

+
The list can be added continuously.

```
class Statement_data(var key : String?, var arr :String?, var arr2 : String?) {

}



  override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                for (snapshot  in p0.children) {
                    for(dSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    
                        var str = dSnapshot.value.toString()
                        var idx = str.indexOf("/")
                        var arr = str.substring(0,idx)
                        var arr2 = str.substring(idx+1)
                 
                        StDataList.add(Statement_data(snapshot.key,arr,arr2))

                        Log.d("Test1", snapshot.key + "/" + dSnapshot.value.toString())
                        Log.d("Test2", arr2.toString())

                    }
                }

                for (i in StDataList.indices) {
                    Log.d("StadataListsize", StDataList.size.toString())
                    Log.d("StDataValue",  StDataList.get(i).key +"/"+ StDataList.get(i).arr + "/" + StDataList.get(i).arr2)

                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: Do you need how much time you spent on work and study for a single day or for all days? Is it allowed to change the database schema?

Comment: Yes can change database schema

Comment: Ok, good to hear that. But please answer this question. Do you need how much time you spent on work and study for a single day or for all days?